# How to find Datomic "db.error" root cause from a stop-on-exception point in the debugger?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, datomic

By debugging using stop-on-exception in a graphical debugger (in the Cursive IDE, which is IntelliJ running Cursive extensions/plugins), I am trying to find out what key/value in my database init script is triggering this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: :db.error/tempid-not-an-entity tempid used only as value in transaction
```

I did find the exception-causing value manually earlier (checking my init file line-by-line), but I want to be able to debug this efficiently from a debugger because of course manually checking line by line is only suitable for toy and very small codebase projects.

For example, I have this edn for the date that is loaded into the database under a transaction:

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/user -900]
 :foo/name "Bar"
 :foo/description "Lorem ipsum dolor."
 :foo/next-foo  #db/id[:db.part/user -901]
 :foo/sub-foos [#db/id[:db.part/user -1100]
                    #db/id[:db.part/user -1102]
                    -1103 ;; ** Intentional Error Inserted *** instead of: #db/id[:db.part/user -1103]
                    ]}
```

and I have this clojure that loads the data:

```
(defn load-data []
  (transact-all (get-conn) (io/resource "data/initial.edn")))
```

I do have a `println` in `transact-all`, which gives me some debug info.  But it doesn't show where the error (the error intentionally inserted as an example above) appears.  It gives me information that looks like this:

```
{:db-before datomic.db.Db@863af762, :db-after datomic.db.Db@100368dd, :tx-data #<ArrayList [datomic.db.Datum@89158c9e]>, :tempids {-9223367638809264727 86, -9223367638809264726 85, -9223367638809264725 84}
```

In the debugger, I do have a stacktrace, but it seems to show only items used for clojure scaffolding such as 'invoke' and 'applyTo'. It is not apparent how to step back to the code where I can see the value that triggered the exception, even though I have the debugger stopped on the exception.

In other environments (such as Java and JavaScript), I am usually able to easily step back from a stop-on-exception condition in the debugger to the point in the code where the actual operation that triggered the exception took place (so that way, it's clear what went wrong).  How can I efficiently debug such errors?

Comment: I'm not sure from how this is phrased if this is a Datomic question or a Cursive/IntelliJ GUI how-to question. Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do to debug and what the block is? The concrete piece here, "how to step back...", looks like a debugger GUI question.

Comment: Ben Kamphaus - I've clarified the question per your request.

Comment: Hey Chris, Would you be able to share the piece of data/code so I can include it in the screencast example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I normally traverse the tree twice, one for entity ids and another one for potential ids references as datom values or entities referenced from other entity maps, building two maps stored in two datoms. Then I convert the map values into sets and get the difference

```
(let [data (read-string (slurp "/tmp/tempid.edn"))
    values (atom #{})
    entities (atom #{})
    walk-values (fn [x]
                  (if (map? x)
                    (doseq [y (vals x)] (swap! values conj y))
                    (when (vector? x) (if (> (count x) 3) (swap! values conj (nth x 3))))
                    )
                  x)
    walk-entities (fn [x]
                    (if (map? x)
                      (when (:db/id x) (swap! entities conj (:db/id x)))
                      (when (coll? x) (if (> (count x) 3) (swap! entities conj (second x))))
                      )
                    x)
    ]
(clojure.walk/postwalk walk-values data)
(clojure.walk/postwalk walk-entities data)
(clojure.set/difference (set (filter #(instance? datomic.db.DbId %)
                                     (map #(if (number? %)
                                            (d/tempid :db.part/user %)
                                            %)
                                          @values)))
                        @entities)
)
```

I sometimes get a little bit of boilerplate (a couple of differences when there is none) but it is very easy to tell when that's the case.

Obviously, data is the binding for the transaction list (which holds both maps and [added? e a v] datoms)